# SonarQube exclude Maven module

Tags: maven, jenkins, sonarqube

I'm running sonar-5.1.2 with Maven / Jenkins CI.

After googling and looking through similar questions (most of them are dated back to 2010-2012), it is still not clear how to exclude a particular Maven module from multi-module Maven project.

**Module Exclusions** property is deprecated since version 4.3 and should not be used anymore.

We have duplicating packages in different modules:

```
root pom.xml
|-module1
  |-my.package.com
|-module2
  |-my.package.com
```

Is it possible to exclude only files from `module2/my.package.com` but include `module1/my.package.com`?

SonarQube analysis is triggered by https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SonarQube+plugin post build action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two [documented options](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+Maven#AnalyzingwithMaven-ExcludingamodulefromSonarQubeanalysis) to exclude a module from a SonarQube analysis; quoting:

> You can either:
>
> - use build profiles to exclude some module (like for integration tests)
> - use Advanced Reactor Options (such as "-pl"). For example mvn sonar:sonar -pl !module2

Since you are using Jenkins, maybe the simpler solution is to use the `-pl` option. This way, you won't change any configuration in your Maven project and you will only change Jenkins configuration.

Comment: Analysis is done as a part of nightly build. Nightly build is executed for all modules. The question is how can I tell sonar not to run analysis for particular module. I can't use -pl and if I exclude some module via maven then there will be no compilation for it.

Comment: @tillias You only need to use `-pl` when running SonarQube analysis, not when the main Maven build is happening.

Comment: SonarQube analysis is triggered by https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SonarQube+plugin post build action. Do you mean some MAVEN_OPTS?

Comment: @tillias I don't have a Jenkins up and running right now but AFAIK, this is done in the build configuration. When you add the Post Build "Sonar", you can click "Advanced" and add Maven properties.

Comment: So I checked possible solutions and all I can find forces me to changed my pom.xml(s) and build procedure. I want it to be filtered by sonar iteself on the filesystem level (not by maven)

Comment: @tillias When you click "Advanced" on the Sonar post-build action, you can add "Additional Properties" (take a loot at [this](https://deors.files.wordpress.com/2014/07/sonar-post-build.png) screeshot). Add the `pl` option here, it should work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92106/discussion-between-tillias-and-tunaki).

Answer (score 0):

As documented [here](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Maven#AnalyzingwithSonarQubeScannerforMaven-ExcludingamodulefromSonarQubeanalysis) you can define property

> `<sonar.skip>true</sonar.skip>`

in the pom.xml of the module you want to exclude

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with a multi-module RCP application for which I could not use -pl because the projects I needed to exclude from analysis were still needed for tycho/maven.

I could not simply change the POM of those projects due to not owning the code (and not wanting to mess with versionning).

I also could not filter by package (using sonar.exclusions) because the packages of those modules were very simple and generic words.

Therefore I decided to use the pipeline code to add the property "sonar.skip" to the POM of each excluded project dynamically and it worked perfectly.

For anyone who might be stuck like me, here is the code to do that (using AWK on Linux):

```groovy
// Update the given POM file with the sonar.skip property set to true
def setSonarSkip(file) {e
    def awk_cmd = '\'BEGIN { propStr="    <sonar.skip>true</sonar.skip>"; fullpropStr="<properties>\\n" propStr "\\n</properties>\\n" } NR==FNR { if ($0 == "<properties>") props=1 ; next } /<\\/project>/ { if (props == 0) print fullpropStr } /<\\/properties>/ { print propStr } { print } \''

    sh "awk ${awk_cmd} ${file} ${file} > tmp"
    sh "cp tmp ${file}"
    sh "rm -f tmp"
}
```

To use it, place this function declaration at the beginning of the pipeline script, then in your stage, you can simply call it like this right after checking the code out:

```groovy
// Exclusions
setSonarSkip("module1/pom.xml")
setSonarSkip("module1/module1a/pom.xml")
setSonarSkip("module2/pom.xml")
setSonarSkip("module4/pom.xml")
```

Hope it is useful

Answer (score 0):

Instead of excluding a module, you can specify the modules you want to scan for. And it's pretty easy to do.
Just specify in `sonar:sonar` goal parameters where the sources and reportPaths are located for the required modules and declare jacoco configuration for each module respectively. As a result, it will look something like this:

1. Jacoco plugin declaration in each module:

```
<plugin>
     <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
     <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>0.8.7</version>
     <executions>
         <execution>
             <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
             <goals>
                 <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
             </goals>
         </execution>
         <execution>
             <id>report</id>
             <phase>test</phase>
             <goals>
                 <goal>report</goal>
             </goals>
         </execution>
     </executions>
 </plugin>
```

2. Sonar goal execution:

```
mvn clean verify sonar:sonar /
-Dsonar.projectKey=... /
-Dsonar.host.url=... /
-Dsonar.login=... /
-Dsonar.branch.name=... /
-Dsonar.sources=../module1/src/main,../module2/src/main / 
-Dsonar.jacoco.reportPath=module1/target/jacoco.exec,module2/target/jacoco.exec
```

Important! It's required to specify `..` before module name in `-Dsonar.sources` parameter because jacoco plugin in each module can only read content by relative path from it's location.

Answer (score -4):

Remove module2 in your root `pom.xml`.

`<modules>
    <module>module1<module>
 </modules>`

Comment: This will work but deleting his Maven module (or ignoring it completely) is probably not what the OP wants.