# How to exclude entire project from SonarQube coverage and Analysis using <sonar.exclusions> in pom.xml?

Tags: sonarqube, pom.xml

I tried

```
<sonar.exclusions>
**/project1/** , 
**/project2/**/*.java
</sonar.exclusions>
```

in pom.xml under properties tag.

Will it work?

My intention is to exclude all files in project1 and project2 from sonar coverage and analysis.

I don't have access to admin SonarQube. So pom.xml is my only option.

Is it really possible to do through pom.xml ?? 
or should I ask for UI admin access.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SonarQube exclude Maven module](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33080131/sonarqube-exclude-maven-module)

Answer (score 0):

Quoting page ["Analyzing with SonarQube Scanner for Maven"](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Maven#AnalyzingwithSonarQubeScannerforMaven-ExcludingamodulefromSonarQubeanalysis) from documentation:

> You can either:
>
> - define property true in the pom.xml of the module you want to exclude
> - use build profiles to exclude some module (like for integration tests)
> - use Advanced Reactor Options (such as "-pl"). For example mvn sonar:sonar -pl !module2

Comment: and actually this question was already asked before on StackOverflow, but I didn't noticed this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33080131/sonarqube-exclude-maven-module